# Printing out all possibilities for each array?

Tags: c++

I'm basically trying a bunch of online problems that I found on the web and I've been stuck on this guy for 2 hours.

```
string array1[3] = {"He", "She", "They"};
string array2[3] = {"Ran", "Ate", "Sat"};
```

I'm also using `srand(time(NULL));` to randomize the output. Here's my whole code that I have so far:

```
string array1[3] = {"He", "She", "They"};
string array2[3] = {"Ran", "Ate", "Sat"};
srand(time(NULL));

int random1 = rand() % 3;
int random2 = rand() % 3;
cout << array1[random1] << " " << array2[random2];
```

What is the algorithm for getting all possible outputs without outputting the same output more than once?

Example: `He Ran, He Ate, He Sat, She Ran, She Ate, She Sat, They Ran, They Ate, They Sat`... but all randomized?

Comment: [You might want to read this](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper That made me laugh. :D

Comment: Why do you want to use random numbers if you want a specific output? Random numbers are random, every time a different output, and thus a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nine possible combinations. Create an array that has the indices `0`-`8`. Use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to shuffle the array randomly. Then, use the elements of the array as indices to the combinations.

```
int indices[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
std::random_shuffle(indices, indices+9);
```

Complete Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string array1[3] = {"He", "She", "They"};
   std::string array2[3] = {"Ran", "Ate", "Sat"};
   std::srand(std::time(NULL));
   int indices[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
   std::random_shuffle(indices, indices+9);
   for ( auto index : indices )
   {
      int i = index/3;
      int j = index%3;
      std::cout << array1[i] << " " << array2[j] << ", ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
They Sat, They Ran, He Sat, He Ate, She Ate, He Ran, They Ate, She Ran, She Sat,
```

Comment: Isn't `random_shuffle` deprecated?

Comment: You are a genius! This is awesome! Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper, yes, it is in C++14.

Comment: @RSahu, How would one do the same thing, but with three arrays? Just wondering.

Comment: @okay14, if the arrays of `N1`, `N2`, and `N3` elements, create `indices` with `N1*N2*N3` elements.

Comment: @RSahu, And then for the `for( auto index: indices)` statement? What about `i = index/3;` and `int j = index%3`? What would it be for `N3`?

Comment: @okay14, please don't make this a consulting session. Sit down with a pencil and paper and work out the math to go from `index` to `i`, `j`, and `k`.